# Call Batch Script from Shell Script using Git Bash

Tags: batch-file, git-bash

I have a batch script(master.bat) which calls a host of batch scripts. Master.bat:

```
call a.bat
call b.bat
call c.bat
```

The shell script(call_master.sh) that calls this batch script is:

```
echo $PATH
cmd /c master.bat
```

I am invoking this shell script on Windows-7 using Git Bash.
When i run the shell script I don't get any errors but None of the scripts is getting invoked by master.bat. 
What should be done to to do this correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help to [double the slash](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/switches%20with%20forward%20slashes) in the /c switch so it is not interpreted as the C: drive by the shell.

I made a little test, and this was the command and output:

```
$ cmd //c master.bat

> call a.bat

> echo hello from a
hello from a

> call b.bat

> echo hello from b
hello from b

> call c.bat

> echo hello from c
hello from c
```

Here's another reference from the Mingw wiki about [path conversion](http://mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

Comment: Is there a way to run this batch in a new window? I mean, somehow, let it detached from the Git Bash shell flow to evaluate independently.

Comment: Found the answer, it's simply: `start file.bat`